# How to stop a useEffect function with a condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm creating my portfolio website, and the concept is to create a cube that people can interact with. It is possible to move the cube by clicking and dragging the mouse on the cube/screen. However, I'ld like to be able to "lock" the cube, by using a useState (true/false).

Literally, if the cube "isLocked", then we shouldnt be able to use the function within the useEffect hook. Here is a part of my Cube component so far:

```
export default function Cube(props) {
  const [isLocked, setIsLocked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLocked) {
      rotateCube(document.getElementById("cube"));
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }, [isLocked]);

 // Rotate function :
  function rotateCube(cube) {
    var mouseX0 = 0,
      mouseY0 = 0,
      mouseX1 = 0,
      mouseY1 = 0;

    cube.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX0 = e.clientX;
      mouseY0 = e.clientY;
      document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;

   ...
}
```

Comment: `rotateCube` is only ever being called when `isLocked` changes to true? Are you calling it other places outside of the effect? I think I'd just put your `isLocked` check inside of the `rotateCube` function, so that even if it gets called, it won't do anything unless it's allowed

Comment: If you are controlling the "isLocked" state correct, it shouldnt do anything if it locked.
you should check your callbacks of setting the "isLocked" state.

Comment: Where do you uninstall the `cube.onmousedown` listener? The effect should return a cancellation function that does that when the `isLocked` state switches to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Can put check inside dragMouseDown function

```
export default function Cube(props) {
  const [isLocked, setIsLocked] = useState(false);

  // executed once on load
  useEffect(() => {
      rotateCube(document.getElementById("cube"));
  }, []);

 // Rotate function :
  function rotateCube(cube) {
    var mouseX0 = 0,
      mouseY0 = 0,
      mouseX1 = 0,
      mouseY1 = 0;

    cube.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
      // here the check
      if (isLocked) { return false }
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX0 = e.clientX;
      mouseY0 = e.clientY;
      document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

I wonder why you don't use JSX for handling events e.g. `<Cube onMouseDown={onMouseDown} />` ?

Comment: I think I just made it the way that seemed easy for me. But of course I still have many things to discover and try. I'll remember JSX for the next time !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers !
I could actually find out what was happening. As you guys told me, I had to implement the `isLocked` within the `rotateCube` function, and place this entire function in the `useEffect`. Also, I forgot the place `isLocked` in the dependency array.

Here is the code :

```
useEffect(() => {
    rotateCube(document.getElementById("cube"));

    // Rotate function :
    function rotateCube(cube) {
      var mouseX0 = 0,
        mouseY0 = 0,
        mouseX1 = 0,
        mouseY1 = 0;

      if (isLocked === true) {
        cube.onmousedown = closeDragElement;
      }
      if (isLocked === false) {
        cube.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }

      function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        mouseX0 = e.clientX;
        mouseY0 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      }

      function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get new cursor position :
        mouseX1 = e.clientX - mouseX0;
        mouseY1 = (e.clientY - mouseY0) * -1;
        //Set the new cube position :
        cube.style.transform =
          "rotateX(" + mouseY1 / 2 + "deg) rotateY(" + mouseX1 / 2 + "deg)";
      }

      function closeDragElement() {
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    }
  }, [isLocked]);
```